# HibernateEntityQuery and EJBQL restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, ejbql

I've just inherited some code that uses `HibernateEntityQuery` and `EJBQL` restrictions.

There's an "activity" table/entity with various fields, and the existing EJBQL restrictions look like:

```
private final String[] SEARCHRESTRRICTION = { 
    "activity.startDate >= #{activityList.startMonthBeginDate}",
    "activity.startDate <= #{activityList.startMonthEndDate}",
    "activity.cost >= #{activityList.minCost}"
}
```

The table also has seven boolean fields representing days (sun/mon/tue...) which apply for a given activity. Now I'd like to query by days- the user will select days they are interested in, and the filtered results should include activities which match *any* of the days chosen by the user.

For example, if the user checks mon/wed/fri, the query should return all activities for which mon = true OR wed = true OR fri = true.

The problem with `EJBQL` is that it applies the restrictions using `AND`, whereas I need to do something like:

```
select * from activity where
      (mon = true OR wed = true OR fri = true);
```

Is there a way to specify a restriction in the form of "return a result if ANY of the following are true"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the initial filtering to the `setEjbql()` call, which is applied prior to the `setRestrictionExpressionStrings()`.